# Introducing Brevity Into C# / Java

Tags: c#, java, oop

#### Background

Currently, if I want to create a `new` object in C# or Java, I type something similar to the following:

> `List<int> listOfInts = new List<int>(); //C#`
>    `ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(); //Java`

C# 3.0 sought to improve conciseness by implementing the following compiler trick:

> `var listofInts = new List<int>();`

#### Question

Since the compiler already knows that I want to create a new object of a certain type (By the fact that I'm instantiating it without assigning it a `null` reference or assigning a specific method to instantiate it), then why can't I do the following?

```
    //default constructors with no parameters:
    List<int> listOfInts = new(); //c#
    ArrayList<String> data = new(); //Java
```

#### Follow Up Questions:

1. What are possible pitfalls of this approach. What edge cases could I be missing?
2. Would there be other ways to shorten instantiation (without using VB6-esque `var`) and still retain meaning?

NOTE: One of the main benefits I see in a feature like this is clarity.  Let say var wasn't limited. To me it is useless, its going to get the assignment from the right, so why bother?  New() to me actually shortens it an gives meaning.  Its a new() whatever you declared, which to me would be clear and concise.

Comment: This is kind of a bad example for Java since List is an interface.

Comment: List in this example is not an interface, it is a generic class.

Comment: Ok, I will edit it then, I haven't used it in while, but thought it was relevant.

Comment: I still think the C# var way is better since it would cover both constructors with and without parameters. So all that is missing is support for class scoped vars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that would be a nice feature. A better example would be where even more typing is required:

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Life would be easier, albeit only slightly, if that could be instantiated as:

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary = new();
```

and:

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary = { {"a",1}, {"b",2} };
```

Comment: Yeah but I still have to type "new Dictionary...." and we're talking about optimising laziness here :).

Comment: True, but I am really talking about saving time and keystrokes for something I already know about my object.

Comment: @rickschott yeah I saw that as well :). Was only a little bit of a wait!

Answer (score 33):

C# saves in the other end:

```
var listOfInts = new List<int>();
```

Comment: This is a .net 3.0+ implementation. is there a 2.0 version that works as well or do you still have to do it like List<int> listOfInts = new List<int>();?

Comment: It's not .NET 3.0. It's C# 3.0. You can still use it when targeting .NET 2.0. But no, there's no equivalent in C# 2.0.

Comment: @Ioxp - You can make 2.0 assemblies with var perfectly fine. var is a C# 3.0 compiler feature. The compiled code is identical to an explicitly typed variable.

Answer (score 16):

> What edge cases could I be missing?

I briefly discussed this possible C# syntax on my [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx) in January. See the comments to that post for some reader feedback on the pros and cons of the syntax.

> Would there be other ways to shorten instantiation (without using VB6-esque var) and still retain meaning?

Possibly, yes.

"var" in C#, however, is nothing like "variant" in VB6. "var" does not mean the same thing as "object", nor does it introduce dynamic typing or duck typing. It is simply a syntactic sugar for [eliminating the redundant stating of the type of the right hand side](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2005/09/27/c-3-0-is-still-statically-typed-honest.aspx).

Answer (score 15):

In C# 3 there's already the mirror image for local variables, implicitly typing:

```
var listOfInts = new List<int>();
```

This [doesn't work for non-local variables](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx) though.

In Java, type inference takes into the assignment target into account, so using static imports and cunning libraries such as the [Google Java Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) you can write code such as:

```
List<Integer> integers = newArrayList();
```

Note that that keeps the variable interface-based while specifying the implementation in the construction side, which is nice.

Comment: Doesn't var have scope limitations?

Comment: What do you mean? It's only for local variables - will edit to make that clearer.

Answer (score 6):

In the new Java 7 proposals there's a type inference proposal, which will life easier re. generics declarations.

e.g.

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

vs

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<>();
```

See [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-February/000009.html) for more information.

Comment: There also was a `final anagrams = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();' proposal somewhere in the closures discussion.

Comment: What I like of this proposal is that you can still keep the interface type and implementation type separate while not having to repeat the generic type information.

Answer (score 5):

In general when using object oriented approaches, you will often create more instances of a more specific type than your variable. Also, it is often a good idea to use a less specific type or an interface. In those cases, this would not make sense.

Think of interfaces:

```
IList<int> = new(); // What instance should the compiler infer?
```

Also, from a technical point of view, the signature of an operation does not include its return type, so that this kind of assignment would be completely different from the normal case.

Answer (score 4):

Your version is less readable, sorry.

Code is meant to be read by humans, only incidentally by machines.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is absolutely false.
Code is made to be primarily readable to machines, otherwise there would be no such thing as a syntax error.

Comment: @John - I would disagree. Code is made for humans. Compiled code on the other hand is for machines. There is a reason for why we code in C# and not IL or machine code.

Comment: @John Gietzen: Actually, code should be *readable* by humans and *interpetable* by machines. Compilers, etc. don't care about the formatting of code (at least for most languages) but humans certainly do.

Comment: @John: "Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute." 
- Abelson and Sussman

Comment: This discussion reminds me of the phrase "Live each day as if it were your last", and how Homer Simpson responded by sitting on the ground crying "Oh God, I don't want to die!! I'm too young! Why me?"

Answer (score 2):

C# has:

```
var listOfInts = new List<int>();
```

which achieves kind of the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, there's

```
var listOfInts = new List<int>();
```

Answer (score 2):

C# 3.0 has a mechanism to reduce the duplication in typing, but it is done by being vague about the type you're declaring, but explicit in the type you are constructing:

e.g.

```
var listOfInts = new List<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

in C#, theres already something like this namely:

```
var listOfInts = new List<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java this doesn't make too much sense, as you will usually declare variables with the interface type:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It would, however, in most cases make sense to be able to omit the declaration of the generic type without compiler warnings, such as:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList();
```

But as Java is always very explicit and verbose about everything, this might as well stay the same.

(And why again would anyone code C# or Java without an IDE?)

EDIT:

Oh, there's a proposal for that! Sweet. Thanks, Brian.

Answer (score 0):

Java has

```
 List<String> data = newList(); //Java, where newList() is a helper method to create an ArrayList();
 List<String> data = newList("Hello", "World"); // a helper method which takes a T....
 Map<String, List<String>> anagrams = newMap(); // Java, where newMap creates a new  HashMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is read from left to right (if your language is not right to left).

That means that

```
var someTypeWithALongName = new TypeWithALongName<TypeParamOne,TypeParamTwo>();
```

puts important data to the right part (actual method / type constructor that is used to init variable, from which a reader of the code can infer knowledge about *actual var type*), which is less convenient to eye, compared to when it is located in the left.

What author suggests however is much better for a left to right reading human - we declare a variable of known type (not some unknown var type)

```
TypeWithALongName<TypeParamOne,TypeParamTwo> someTypeWithALongName = new();
```

now important data (actual type that variable will have) is to the left, we can scan code on left side and notice actual types, not a fence of var declarations

```
var x = ....;
var y = ....;
var z = ....;
var xy = ....;
```

`Code Complete` book states that readability is the most important, and I find it hard to disagree with that. Saving 5(or less) seconds and using `var` instead of real type easily makes code review in future harder, can make code unreadable depending on the right part, and can plant unexpected errors that will be very hard to notice. All with the value of.. saving 5 seconds and not writing a declaring type for variable?

It is now a common knowledge that actual **code writing** is not taking that much time out of whole time consumed for program creation,especially if it is a *product* program) ( which usually has debugging, system testing, components integration, design, meetings, etc taking **MUCH** more time that actual code writing)

On other hand when we type

```
TypeWithALongName<TypeParamOne,TypeParamTwo> someTypeWithALongName = new();
```

I find it hard not to interpret that line as anything but calling a default constructor for type and creating an instance of the type.

Also in case of wall of initializations we get actual type names on the beginning of the line, so its easy to scan code from top to bottom and we don't have to move eyes to the end of string to know what actually this concrete var initialization does.( And if you think scanning line to end is a free roll task , first of all its not, and with var its not just scanning, its also checking whether there is a bug in the right part of initialization (for example method with different return type is called or some other types of bugs which var allows))

```
TypeWithALongName<TypeParamOne,TypeParamTwo> someTypeWithALongName = new();
AnotherTypeWithLongNname someAnotherTypeWithLongNname = new();
List<int> idList = new();
Dictionary<int,string> lookupDict = new ();
```

I am against `var` use except for cases it was created for (anonymous types , generally coming from LINQ), and if we were to save up some space in a code I would prefer any code reducing strategies were happening on the right side.

I also believe that using `var` to declare a variable and assigning it to a return value of some method highly complicates code analysis and often introduces hard to catch bugs, that would have been completely avoided if var wasn't possible for such cases, so if only the constructors code could be shortened to a `new()` or `new(ParamType param)` and not some other method like

```
var x = someTypeLocalIstance.ComputeResults()
```

readability will only win once more.

Answer (score 0):

I think Microsoft made it this way: a)  `var xy = new MyClass();`

instead of this way: b) `MyClass xy = new();`

because a) is capable to hold anonymous classes and with b) that would not be possible.